# NHibernate: "collection was not processed by flush()" caused by lazy loading issue

Tags: nhibernate

I have two classes:

```
class Parent
{
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}

class Child 
{
    public virtual IList<GrandChild> GrandChildren { get; set; }
}
```

I have an instance of `Parent` loaded from my `ISession`, `Parent.Child` is lazy loaded (NOT loaded at this point). Child.GrandChildren is also lazy loaded.

If I do this:

```
session.Save(new Parent { Child = existingParent.Child } );
```

I get `collection [Child.GrandChildren] was not processed by flush()`

If I cause `existingParent`'s `Child` property to be loaded, simply by accessing it:

```
var x = existingParent.Child.Name
```

the problem goes away. Why is this happening, and how do I solve it - preferably without having to change my fetching strategy?

**Edit: ** Parent has a FK to Child

I'm using NH 2.1.2.4000

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a fix that does not involve touching the collection?

Comment: unless "use a document db, instead" counts

Comment: Thank you for posting your workaround. This has been a pain-point for me and your workaround delivered in a crunch until a permanent solution can be found (up to and including moving to EF). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, the comment from @Jamie Ide helped me realized what the problem was. I was initializing the collection inside the constructor, which made NHibernate think that the collection was dirty, even if it wasn't required to save that specific object at that point.

The exception I got was: 
ClassName: ERROR | NHibernate.AssertionFailure: collection [CollectionName] was not processed by flush()

I still want to do this initialization, but I guess I have to find some other solution to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is the cascade setting for cascading changes from Child to the GrandChildren collection? I think NHibernate throws this exception if the collection is dirty but the cascade setting does not cause the changes to be persisted.

Comment: ive not made any changes hence why its not loaded?
i just want to make a new `parent`, with the same child as an existing `parent`. cascade for hasone is `saveupdate` and for hasmany is `alldeleteorphan`

Comment: Are you initializing the GrandChildren collection in Child's constructor? Please show the mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session.Load` to reference an existing instance of `Child` without making a trip to the db. This should do it, I think:

```
session.Save(new Parent { Child = session.Load(existingParent.Child.Id) } );
```

But check to make sure that the `.Id` call doesn't trigger a db trip.